# Executing powershell from ConEmu command prompt does nothing

Tags: windows-10, powershell, conemu

If I open a regular Command prompt in Win 10, via <Win key>, `cmd`, and at the prompt I type `powershell`, I get a PowerShell command prompt.

But if I get a Windows command prompt in ConEmu (v.18.06.26 [32] from PortableApps, **EDIT**: Updated to v21.04.22 (preview)), and I type `powershell`, it does nothing.

So I tried in ConEmu to *Setup tasks*, and set up a `PowerShell` task, the same way as I do with a `cmd` prompt (I actually used a builtin task).
Then when launching that task I get a tab with only the message `Press Enter or Esc to exit...` (and I don't know who is responsible for that message).

**Is there anything particular I have to do to get a powershell prompt in ConEmu?**

Notes:

1. During the update, a window showed up in what I guess it was the post-install, with an error message related to 7-zip. I lost that window, but ConEmu works "fine".
2. The application icons for the new version changed to  
   [image]  
   but the PortableApps launcher still shows the old icon and version in the tooltip   
   [image]
3. I have another ConEmu in my system (I did not know until today) which came with GitExtensions. That is v20.07.13 and I see the same here.  
   [image]

Comment: Please tell us which ConEmu version or bundle do you use

Comment: @Maximus - Updated OP. I guess you are the developer of ConEmu, so you would probably hit the nail in the head.

Comment: Please update your version, it's three years old. In general, the answer is - "you have not to do anything particular, just run Powershell."

Comment: @Maximus - Things haven't change after the update, please see EDIT.
See also edited 3rd paragraph, which better describes what I was seeing with a PowerShell task.

Comment: @Maximus - ... and the answer with new findings.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I installed ConEmu Alpha for PortableApps version 210718 (did not have it installed before). Typing powershell on my side works as expected.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - Thanks for checking. Will tinker further.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - Could you please check what do you have in *Setup tasks...* -> *Startup* -> *Tasks* -> *{Shells::cmd}* (or *{cmd}*)?

Comment: @Maximus - I posted an answer, could you comment?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I have [{cmd}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTQ8W.png).

Answer (score 0):

I launched the builtin compound task `Shells::cmd 64/32`, which has the following definition

```
> "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /k ""%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd" & echo This is Native cmd.exe"

"%windir%\syswow64\cmd.exe" /k ""%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd" & echo This is 32 bit cmd.exe -new_console:s50V"
```

The differences between them are (confirmed by later launching them as separate shells):

```
Task    Version*1     "Sensitive"       Warning at
                     to powershell?     launching*2
Top      AMD64      No, as in Fig. 1        No
Bottom    x86         Yes (normal)      As in Fig. 2
```

*1 Confirmed by `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`, the output of which is listed in the table.

*2 Upon first launching the terminal, the warning below popped up.

**Fig. 1**
[image]

**Fig. 2**
[image]

Then I checked if that was an issue intrinsically related to windows
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` vs.
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`.
And it was not, since executing directly any of the two from the <Win key> dialog, and then `powershell` in the command prompt, led to "normal" behavior.
I also checked that all shortcuts that I was launching via <Win key>, which also led to "normal" behavior, called
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, the "failing" variant under ConEmu.

My conclusion is that the problem is somehow specific to ConEmu.
Under ConEmu, task definitions

```
cmd -new_console:C:cmd.exe
```

or

```
"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /k ""%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd" & echo This is Native cmd.exe"
```

are the cause of the problem.

If I type <Win key> and there I execute `cmd -new_console:C:cmd.exe`, and `powershell` in the command prompt, I get "normal" behavior.

If I run either `%windir%\syswow32\cmd.exe` or `%windir%\syswow64\cmd.exe` from the <Win key> dialog, `set path` in those shells returns

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.2.180\windows\mpi\intel64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\ecl\macros\;C:\<myappsdir2>\utils\gtools;C:\<myappsdir2>\miktex\bin\x64
```

OTOH, `set path` from either of the two ConEmu shells returns the same string as above, prepended with

```
C:\<myappsdir1>\ConEmu\App\ConEmu\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\<myappsdir1>\ConEmu\App\ConEmu;C:\<myappsdir1>\ConEmu\App\ConEmu\ConEmu;
```

Further digging may be useful.
I wonder why nobody reported this issue, which apparently shows up with the PowerShell taks under builtin conditions, and apparently for the PortableApps version and also the one that comes with GitExtensions.

**Related**:

https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/965

Comment: What is the `set PATH` output of both cmds?

Comment: @Maximus - Please see EDITed answer, with a lot of new info.

Comment: "wrong version packet" is  VERY bad message, your installation is broken. Please update all binaries.

Comment: @Maximus - I have just reinstalled the `.paf.exe` from scratch, same behaviour.

Comment: Please take a ProcessExplorer and check the full path of the ConEmuHk.dll loaded in cmd.exe. My guess, that ConEmuHk.dll loaded into 32-bit cmd (from syswow64) has still the wrong version.